# Create Vertical List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-animation, flutter-listview, flutter-pageview

I want to create this type of listview using flutter.
https://dribbble.com/shots/6872462-Food-ordering-app-Animate
You can find out more by clicking on this link. But I don't know how to create this type of list. I mean, you can see in the GIF that the list is indexed based.
A fixed indexed item container is colored.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter provides you with a widget very similar to the result you want to achieve called [`NavigationRail`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html).
You will not have the animation by default, but you can maybe search in the source code of this widget how to create a custom widget that will implement animations.